# How to print all lines except the line before a pattern in file using awk

Tags: perl, printing, sed, awk

How can we do this with awk?

**Input file**

```
Line 1
Line 2
####PATTERN####### (Line 3)
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
####PATTERN####### (line 7)
Line 8
####PATTERN####### (Line 9)
```

etc..

**output file**

```
Line 1
Line 3
Line 4 
Line 5
Line 7
Line 9
```

Comment: Your output file is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish here. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I would like to remove each line that is found before a pattern. In the example above, line 2,6 and 8 should be removed. Does it clarify the goal? Thank you!

Comment: The following prints only the line before the pattern: awk !'/"1";/{!print x};{x=$0}' - but I wish to get the opposite

Comment: @user2605165 You do realize that your output contains lines that do not exist in the input?

Comment: In this case, the pattern is in line 3, 7, and 9, which ones I would like to keep as well. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @user2605165 Not that it really matters, but you do understand that repeating the same thing three times does not clarify things, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with `awk`:

```
awk '/PATTERN/{for(;i<NR-2;)print lines[++i];i=NR;delete lines;print $0}{lines[NR]=$0}' file
```

#### Output:

```
$ cat file
Line 1
Line 2
####PATTERN####### (Line 3)
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
####PATTERN####### (line 7)
Line 8
####PATTERN####### (Line 9)
$ awk '/PATTERN/{for(;i<NR-2;)print lines[++i];i=NR;delete lines;print $0}{lines[NR]=$0}' file
Line 1
####PATTERN####### (Line 3)
Line 4
Line 5
####PATTERN####### (line 7)
####PATTERN####### (Line 9)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you delete line #9 from the example file.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '$!N;s/.*####PATTERN####### \(.*\)/\1/;P;D' text
```

#### Output

```
Line 1
(Line 3)
Line 4
Line 5
(line 7)
(Line 9)
```

The `N` command grabs the next line from the input into the *pattern space* so that we can perform a pattern matching against two lines. If we discover `####PATTERN######` in the middle, we only keep the second part so that the previous line is deleted. The `P` command prints the resulted pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Code for [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -nr '/####PATTERN#######/!{x;1!p;x};$p;h' file
```

---

```
$ sed -nr '/####PATTERN#######/!{x;1!p;x};$p;h' file
Line 1
####PATTERN####### (Line 3)
Line 4
Line 5
####PATTERN####### (line 7)
####PATTERN####### (Line 9)
```

---

Code for GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /PATTERN/ && NR>1) {delete l[(NR-1)]}; l[NR]=$0}END {for (a in l) print l[a]}' file
```

```
$ awk '{if ($0 ~ /PATTERN/ && NR>1) {delete l[(NR-1)]}; l[NR]=$0}END {for (a in l) print l[a]}' file
Line 1
####PATTERN####### (Line 3)
Line 4
Line 5
####PATTERN####### (line 7)
####PATTERN####### (Line 9)
```